# How to remove a cloud armor secuiry policy from backend service using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm creating a few GCP cloud armor policies across multiple projects using the Python client library and attaching them to several backend services using the `.set_security_policy()` method

1. I know you can do it [using the console / gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#remove-policies)  but I need to automate this in Python
2. I've tried the `.update()` method in google-cloud-compute but that did not work out

```
from google.cloud import compute, compute_v1

client = compute.BackendServicesClient()
backend_service_resource = compute_v1.types.BackendService(security_policy="")
client.update(project='project_id',
             backend_service='backend_service',
             backend_service_resource=backend_service_resource)
```

The error I got when running the above code is

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 PUT https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<project-id>/global/backendServices/<backend-name>: Invalid value for field 'resource.loadBalancingScheme': 'INVALID_LOAD_BALANCING_SCHEME'. Cannot change load balancing scheme.
```

When I specify `loadBalancingScheme` then the same error occurs with another resource value. At run-time I would not have information of all the meta data of the backend-service and some meta-data might not be initialized in the first place.

Comment: How do you know the update method didn't work out? What error are you getting?

Comment: @GilesRoberts 

`google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 PUT https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<project-id>/global/backendServices/<backend-name>: Invalid value for field 'resource.loadBalancingScheme': 'INVALID_LOAD_BALANCING_SCHEME'. Cannot change load balancing scheme.`

I though that I would need to mention the loadBalancingScheme in the resource but when I do that I get the same error but with a different resource value. I would not know all the features of the backend while deleting and would knowing the name of the backend

Comment: Please add the above error to the question.

Comment: As a backstop, can you use Python to execute the console commands that you know work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for anyone who had similar issues in the future. I was originally going to call the gcloud commands through python using `os.system()` as @giles-roberts recommended, but then I stumbled across a proper way to to do this using the Client Libraries

You simply use the same `.set_security_policy()` to set the security policy in the first place but this time make the policy as `None`. This is not quite obvious since the name of the security policy has to be a string in the documentation and it does not accept an empty string either.

```
from google.cloud import compute, compute_v1

client = compute.BackendServicesClient()
resource = compute_v1.types.SecurityPolicyReference(security_policy=None)
error = client.set_security_policy(project='<project_id>',
                                   backend_service='<backend_service>',
                                   security_policy_reference_resource=resource)
```